# Multiple PIDs for Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When Jupyter notebook starts in my centos 7, It is spawning multiple processes with different process ids (147 unique PIDs). Inspite of shutting down all my notebooks, I see every of those PIDs are running .

```
pgrep 'jupyter' | wc -l
147
```

When I start any new notebook, count of processes are not increasing. It is the same as earlier.

How do I reduce the number of process Jupyter spwans?
Is there any way to monitor health of Jupyter server?

Comment: Same issue for me as well

Answer (score 0):

One process corresponds to one instance of the kernel. Therefore, each running notebook on your jupyter lab server is a process. And hence, the several PIDs.